# HapiJS Request Life-cycle

Tags: node.js, socket.io, httprequest, server-sent-events, hapi.js

Can anyone help me with SSE? I'm trying to sent SSE using Susie (https://github.com/mtharrison/susie). Of course the request life-cycle doesn't allow me to reply twice. so doing a `reply.event` and a `reply.view` in my route handler does not work. Any suggestions?

Here is an example:

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/SSE',
    handler: function(request, reply) {
        reply.event({id: 2, data: 'test data' });
        /** I want to reply with a view as well after I send the SSE */
        reply.view('SSE/index');
    }
}
```

I was thinking that one way to do this is to stop using **susie** and just send SSE manually, then I should be able to `reply.view` I think. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also any links to further documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Obviously I get the "cannot call reply interface twice" error with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Just ended up using Socket.io. Couldn't get SSE to work the way I wanted to under Hapijs.

**Client Side**

*index.html*

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect();
  socket.on('event', function (data) {
     console.log(data);
  });
</script>
```

**Server Side**

*app.js*

```
// Export Socket.io io variable for use in routes file
    exports.io = require('socket.io')(server.listener);
```

*routes/index.js*

```
// Emit event to all connected users
app.io.emit('event', { data: 'test message'});
```